# -initWithFrame method is being called twice

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nib

I have written a code to load a nib file which consists of a view and a tableview. Everything works fine as expected but when i run the program, sometimes the views gets loaded, sometimes it doesnot. I mean, when i run my application say for the first time, it will open a proper GUI window with all the views in place. when i re-open the second time, it will not load the view. then if i close the application and open again, it will again open properly. This happens inconsistently and i am not able to figure out where the problem might be. One thing i figured out is that my "initWithFrame" function is being called twice.I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Please add some code. Otherwise it's very difficult to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, if you can make a sample application available, it would be far easier to figure out what might be going wrong. It could be nearly anything at this point.

Comment: What “`initWithFrame` function”? `initWithFrame:` is normally a method of NSView classes. What class or classes have you overridden it in? What view or views are being initialized? Is the same view being initialized once, or are multiple views being initialized? (Check the last bit by NSLogging self.)